# How to print a Tag Cloud using Java Canvas and Rectangles

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics

My program's goal is to print a Tag Cloud of words from a TreeMap of Strings with integer values. The string with the highest number will be the word with the biggest font and so on. The only issue I am seeming to have is with intersecting words when printed. I have been using rectangles with text inside in order to detect intersections using the intersect method. My idea was to start all the words from the center and move each one out in a random direction(up, down, left, or right) until the text box no longer intersects any other box. This was to ensure as little white space between the words as possible without intersection.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class draw extends Canvas{
    
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    public draw() {
        map.put("kaylen", 16);
        map.put("mia", 17);
        map.put("isabel", 19);
        map.put("sarah", 15);
        map.put("natalie", 20);
        map.put("emily", 5);
        map.put("chang", 12);
        map.put("dorothy", 2);
        map.put("victoria", 17);
        map.put("katie", 25);
        map.put("hannah", 14);
        map.put("megan", 9);
        map.put("grace", 25);
        map.put("rachel", 18);
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics window){

    setBackground(Color.white);
    ArrayList<Integer> sortHighLow = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //used to sort the values from high to low
    ArrayList<String> wordsDescend = new ArrayList<String>(); //list of strings in descending value based on points

    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        Integer  a = entry.getValue();
        sortHighLow.add(a);
    }

    Collections.sort(sortHighLow, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for(Integer i: sortHighLow) {
        for( Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet() ){
            if(entry.getValue()==i && !wordsDescend.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                wordsDescend.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }       


    int largest = 200; //largest font size
    int count = 0;
    Rectangle[] rectangles;
    
    

    ArrayList<Integer> width = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //list of each individual string/box's width
    ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //list of each individual string/box's height
    ArrayList<Integer> fonts = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //list of each string's font sizes
    
    for(String s: wordsDescend) {
//used to create box/rectangle dimensions + font sizes

       int x = 400;//(int)(Math.random() * (700 - 100 + 1) + 100);
       int y = 400;//(int)(Math.random() * (700 - 100 + 1) + 100);

       AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();     
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform,true,true);
        //window.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, largest-(count*13))); 
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, largest-(count*14));
        fonts.add(largest-(count*14));
        int textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getWidth());
        width.add(textwidth);
        int textheight = (int)(font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getHeight());
        height.add(textheight);
                
        count++;
    }
    
    rectangles = new Rectangle[fonts.size()];
    
    for(int i=0; i < fonts.size(); i++) {
//used initialize each rectangle and assign it in rectangles list
        Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(400, 400, width.get(i), height.get(i));
        rectangles[i]=temp;
    }

//checks to see if a rectangle intersects with any other rectangle and if it does, it moves it and checks again if the new position intersects any other rectangles

    for(int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<rectangles.length; j++) {
            if((i!=j)&&(rectangles[i].intersects(rectangles[j]))) {
                while(rectangles[i].intersects(rectangles[j])) {
                    int change= (int)(Math.random() * (1 - 1 + 1) - 1);
                    int change2= (int)(Math.random() * (1 - 1 + 1) - 1);
                    rectangles[i]= new Rectangle(rectangles[i].x+change, rectangles[i].y+change2, rectangles[i].width, rectangles[i].height);
                }   
            }
            j=0;
        }
    }
    
    for(int x = 0; x<rectangles.length; x++) {
//prints out the strings in set font sizes and colors
        window.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, fonts.get(x))); 
        window.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
        window.drawString(wordsDescend.get(x), rectangles[x].x, rectangles[x].y+rectangles[x].height);
    
    }
}
}
```

Runner:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class drawRunner extends JFrame
{


    public drawRunner()
    {
        super("tag cloud");

        setSize(800,800);

        draw r = new draw();
        
        getContentPane().add(r);

        setVisible(true);
    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        r.paint(getGraphics());
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        drawRunner run = new drawRunner();
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any error message, but my graphics panel refuses to show anything other than a white background. Plus every time I try to close the graphics window, it doesn't close. Is there another method to move the strings? Also, how would you implement both horizontal and vertical strings into the tag cloud instead of just the horizontal strings that I have?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be extending a `JPanel` (or JComponent) for custom painting when using Swing.
2. you override `paintComponent()` for custom painting.
3. the painting methods should NOT change the state of the component, only paint the existing state. This means all of your ArrayLists should be created (and sorted) outside of the painting method.
4. don't use `getGraphics()`. Swing will pass the Graphics object to the paintComponent() methond when Swing determines the component needs to be painted.
5. A painting method should NOT use random logic. The painting method will be invoked multiple times and you don't want the painting to randomly change.
6. Class names should start with an upper case character.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples. Download the working code and make small changes. Then test. Then make another change. Learn the basic of painting first before attempting to write your entire application custom painting.

Comment: (1+) but for (1) I think I would phrase it as "extending a `JPanel` with _custom painting_" instead of _Swing_ "in order to add/change functionality to/of the class (such as `paintComponent()`)."

Comment: @PranavAmarnath *"I think I would phrase it as.."* I look forward to reading your answer! Note: I'm *not* camickr & won't be providing an answer because IMO camickr's answer covers it.